# "Free" energy from Self-Charging capacitors?

Tags: charge, capacitance, electronics

Real world conundrum. I have an old Ac to DC variable Wall adapter. It can output 3v - 12v. It has one capacitor (1000mF 25V  85 Celsius) it also has "MW" which I think is the Mean Well company, a reputable electronics maker (although mw is also a case size for capacitors). I believe it is an Aluminum Electrolytic capacitor. I unplugged the unit and discharged the capacitor. Naturally 0V was measured (at the output leads of the circuit).  But the voltage immediately began climbing. I discharged the capacitor again. Voltage went to zero and immediately began climbing. I have done this about 6 times and voltage always increases. In the last 3 trials, it increases by about 0.001V per second for approx 8 seconds then the rate of increase slows.  Over night it grew to 1V.  Can a capacitor self charge? If so what is the physics behind this seemingly "free energy"?

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263790/main-cause-of-self-charging-of-unshorted-capacitors

Answer (score 4):

I got bitten bythis as a teenager. I discharged a high voltage (10kV) capacitor (Milliken's oildrop experiment in the physics lab at our high school) and  went for lunch without leaving the two terminal connected to each other. When I came back I touched the two terminals and got a severe shock. I thus learned the the hard way about [dielectric relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_absorption).  The polarized dielecetric takes time to come back to its unpolarized state, and in doing so it recharges the capacitor plates in the opposite sense to its original charge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way capacitors can self-charge.

When dissimilar objects are rubbed together, it is possible to transfer charge (a.k.a. "static electricity") from one to the other. If a capacitor is connected to one of these objects, it can collect the transferred charge and hold it for surprisingly long times.

If one of the objects doing the rubbing is air (as for example when the other object is standing in the wind) then if the standing object is connected to a large capacitor it can accumulate a huge charge.

A portable capacitor bank wired into a metal trailer and left in the wind did exactly this some years ago. The capacitor system should have been grounded to a metal post stuck in the ground but was not. When a worker opened the trailer and entered it, he accidentally touched the main + terminal for the capacitor bank and in the words of our campus safety officer, he died *exponentially*.

Answer (score 0):

I've read in an internet article about a Leyden jar which can accumulate a voltage left alone by itself if one of the electrodes is earth grounded.
Probable background radioactivity, radio waves or ion accumulation charges the unattended Leyden Jar.

Another interesting charging is the earth grounded Electrophorus which after an initial friction charging can retain a charge for a very long period of time after discharging.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).